# Extract the last column from a list of data frames

Tags: r

I have a list with ten data frames with different number of columns and I would like to get a list with ten vectors. Each vector would be the last column from each data frame.

If I want to get the last column from the first data frame, I run:

```
lapply(list_with_df,function(x) x[,lengths(list_with_df)[1]])
```

But I have got the same column number for each data frame.

I have tried to do a "loop for" through the ten data frames, but I have got an error. I appreciate if someone could help me with this matter. Regards.

Comment: What about `lapply(list_with_df,function(x) x[,ncol(x)])` ?

Comment: Thank you very much, it works really well. Do you want me to get reputation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `lengths` you can ask of the number of columns by `ncol`. This should work:

```
lapply(list_with_df,function(x) x[,ncol(x)])
```

**Edit**

Just for some clarification: The reason why you got *the same column number for each data frame* is because you have always selected the column number according to the first element of `lengths` vector by using `lengths(list_with_df)[1]`. It was always the length of the first `data.frame`

Comment: Just to add on to this (I found it very helpful!) you can also use the `purrr` mapping functions in the same way: `map(list_with_df, ~.x[,ncol(.x)])`.